# Making map in R of Belgium using the tmap library

Tags: r, dictionary, tmap

I would like to make a map of Belgium and its provinces in R using the 'tmap' library, but I need to specify the shape object, but where can I find this data for Belgium?

```
tm_shape(Belgium) + tm_polygons()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it already,

```
install.packages('spDataLarge', repos='https://nowosad.github.io/drat/', type='source')
library(spDataLarge)
data(BE_ADMIN_PROVINCE) 
tm_shape(BE_ADMIN_PROVINCE) +  tm_polygons()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, I recommend checking [CRAN Task View: Analysis of Spatial Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html).

Specifically, my choices are **giscoR** and **GADMTools**:

```r
library(tmap)
library(giscoR)

be <- gisco_get_nuts(resolution = "1", country = "BE", nuts_level = 2)


tm_shape(be) +
  tm_polygons()
```

[image]

```r
library(GADMTools)


be2 <- gadm_sf_loadCountries("BEL", level = 2)$sf

tm_shape(be2) +
  tm_polygons()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>